# Return from the max function Stepanov Notes

Tags: c++

`max()` template according to Stepanov Notes intentionally return

```
b<a?a:b
```

instead of

```
a<b?b:a
```

to ensure that the function behaves correctly even if the two values are **equivalent but not equal**
Few explanations over here but still couldn't understand 
http://stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf (page 63)

I am not able to think of a use case when two values will be equivalent but not equal

Comment: Not sure if it applies here or not but `NaN` does not equal `NaN`.

Comment: In the document you've linked, the word "equal" (or "equality") only appears on page  57, and then again on page 68. I'm not sure what you're quoting here.

Comment: If you have overidden `operator<`. So two instances could be different but have one field that is the same and which is used in the overloaded operator. So they return equivalent, but are actually not equal and it would matter which one is returned. The example sean parent gave for exhibiting this subtle bug was implementing a [clamp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) function.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for the link this what I was looking for

Comment: Duplicate of a duplicate now, you guys are on a roll!
(wonmder how soon we will get duplucate loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `a==b` first returns `b`, second returns `a`

This would triggers when you overload a class's `<` function

e.g.

```
class myClass {
public:
    int key;
    string value;
    bool operator<(const myClass& rhs) {
        return this->key < rhs.key;
    }
}
```

You may need to decide what do you want your program do in a more specific case